# Getting the first record from a table grouped by another record - PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
client_id pet_id   clinic_id invoice_date total service unqid
20.20003  20.26777 20        1/24/2015    100        1     1
20.20001  20.26355 20        1/11/2015     50        2     2
20.20001  20.26355 20        1/12/2015    200              4
20.20001  20.26355 20        1/13/2015    600              5
20.20003  20.26777 20        1/15/2015    350              6
```

From the table above, I am trying to make a sql query that gives me the 'total' of the first(lowest) 'invoice_date' grouped by 'pet_id'.

Using this, I can get an average for the first invoice. Problem is I cant get this to work.

I have tried:

```
mysql_query("SELECT total FROM invoice WHERE clinic_id='$clinic_id' GROUP BY pet_id ORDER BY invoice_date ASC");
```

But this gives me 50, 100
It should be 50 and 350 (Unqid 2 and 6).

How would I accomplish this? Also, why does my query not work? I thought it would give me the total grouped by pet_id (making sure I only get 1 invoice per pet) and ordered by the lowest invoice_date (making sure its the first one).

Comment: You mention something about dates but this is SQL. I see no dates here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT total 
FROM 
 (SELECT * from total order by invoice_date ASC) as invoice 
WHERE clinic_id='$clinic_id' 
GROUP BY pet_id
```

Comment: That works! I don't 100% understand it tho, how does that sub-query make this work?

Comment: GROUP BY may take the first matching item it finds, but there's nothing in the documentation to suggest that it does, and there's nothing to suggest that it will continue to do so in the future!! Performance issues aside, I think it's best to stick with the documented solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Strawberry, this syntax is a work around. When you are using *GROUP BY* conditions, your select should always use aggregate methods.

At the moment, the syntax proposed by andrei.mihail.nicolae works but you don't know for how long.

I propose you this solution using aggregate methods:

```
select a.*
from invoice as a
,(
    select pet_id, min(invoice_date) as invoice_date
    from invoice
    group by pet_id
) as b
where a.pet_id = b.pet_id
and a.invoice_date = b.invoice_date
```